# Search multi-dimension array for any value that matches

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-filter

I have a csv file that opens and places in an array

example of csv file:

```
Steven King, IT

Ronald Dahl, BFG

Charles Abbot, The island
```

So this creates my array with different keys ect for each artist ect. I open up my csv File using the below:

```
$file = fopen('./example.csv','r') or die("can't open file");
while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000)) !== false) {
    $csv[] = $line;
    }
fclose($file) or die("can't close file");
```

Which works fine, but I'm Struggling to search all the array for any value the user searches for; My form posts the users string and search the array for any value that matches what the user enters (not case senstive). ie:

```
//gets the users input from form
$user_string = $_POST['search_string'];
```

Lets say the user enters stephen or island, im trying to get it to search the $csv array for any value that matches or contain the string and output all values on that key. I have tried using array_filter & preg_grep but not having much luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need array search function for confirm when you create the $cvs array in loop. You can create the results in this loop. Here is a sample.

```
<?php

$file = fopen('example.csv', 'r') or die("can't open file");

$results = []; // it'll hide php notifications

$searchword = $_POST['search_string'];

while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000)) !== false) {

    $found = false;

    foreach ($line as $var => $val) {
        if (stristr($val, $searchword) || stristr($var, $searchword)) {
            $found = true;
        }
    }

    if ($found == true) {
        $results[] = $line;
    }
}

fclose($file) or die("can't close file");

print_r($results);
```

Comment: Thanks Mehmet, Im still having trouble with it placing the line in the results array. ie it prints out an empty array. Am i missing something?

Comment: the cvs file is true ? because it's start with dot (.)

Comment: Sorry that was my error, yes i do have the correct file path for the file but it wont add the the values to the results array, not sure if the array_search() function is working.

Comment: I fixed the answer, can you try now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional approach:

```
$f = array_filter($csv, function($cs) use($user_string){ foreach($cs as $c){return stristr($c,$user_string);}});
```

Since you were able to create an array from your csv file, simply pass that array to `array_filter` and then loop through every array using `foreach` and use `stristr` to return all values that match your search needle.

```
$arr = [
 0 => [
  "name" => "Stephen King",
  "movie" => "IT"
  ],
 1 => [
  "name" => "Ronald Dahl",
  "movie" => "BFG"
  ],
2 => [
  "name" => "Charles Abbot",
  "movie" => "The Island"
  ]
];

$n = "Ron";

$f = array_filter($arr, function($ar) use($n){ foreach($ar as $a){return stristr($a,$n);}});

var_dump($f);
```